# Command Blocks and Redstone Comparators

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-commands

So I am giving Command Blocks a first try and I've found that with the comparator you can make it so it perceives a player is near them (and of course if you use the [r=x] tag. 
The scenario I am trying to make is one where are 2 players or more, (player N and player M.)

- N is in range and the Command Block's condition applies.
- M enters the range while N also is in it. Condition applies too.

Essentially, I am trying to make a bubble that, whenever someone enters, gets the perks of being inside without the need of the other one leaving; on the contrary, I am getting no change if someone is in range already.

The layout I am using is the following: 
[image: redstone layout]

By the way, I know this work if people take turns, but I want them to work even when there is someone in the range already, so I am open to change the layout if necessary.

 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the down side of using comparators. NOT MP friendly. When one player enters, the command block is already triggered.

Solution 1:

This will constantly re-apply the perk to anyone in range.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add inRange dummy
```

Clock(20tps Fill Clock)

```
/scoreboard players set @a inRange 0
/scoreboard players set @a[x=<X>,y=<Y>,z=<Z>,r=<Range>] inRange 1
Run commands that will give the perks using the player selector @a[score_inRange_min = 1]
```

Solution 2:

Simpler version of Solution 1

Clock(20tps Fill Clock)

```
Run commands that will give the perks using the player selector @a[x=<X>,y=<Y>,z=<Z>,r=<Range>
```

Solution 3:

Give perk upon entering range.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objective add inRange dummy
```

Clock(20tps Fill Clock)

```
Run Commands that will give the perks using the player selector @a[x=<X>,y=<Y>,z=<Z>,r=<Range>,score_inRange = 0]
/scoreboard players set @a inRange 0
/scoreboard players set @a[x=<X>,y=<Y>,z=<Z>,r=<Range>] inRange 1
```

Explanation:

Solution 1:

First reset the score of all players. Then mark all players within range on a scoreboard, and finally run a command on all marked players.

Solution 2:

Straight up run a command on all players within range

Solution 3:

Run a command on all players that are in range but have not been marked aka. just entered the range. Then reset the score and mark all players in range.